# why macro does not work in this situation?

Tags: c

I have the code follow:

```
funcA() {
   #define strdup(a) NULL
   funcB();
}
```

While funcB() in **another file**. I find that the marco `strdup(a)` does not work.How can I make it work?

Comment: Defining macros with the same name as standard library names is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I am doing the unit testing.

Answer (score 4):

I assume `funcB` uses `strdup`, otherwise your question doesn't make sense.

Macros are only relevant in the preprocessor and do not propagate to different compilation units. If `funcB` is in a different compilation unit then the macro needs to be defined there too, this is generally achieved through including a header with the macro into all compilation units that need it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because, the source file containing `funcB` has no knowledge of your macro.

Macro are expanded during the preprocessing and do not propagate to different translation unit. That is, a common way to solve this problem is to put the macro definition inside a header file. Included by every source file which need the macro definition.

Also from the C standard:

> **6.10.3.5 Scope of macro deﬁnitions**
>
> A macro deﬁnition lasts (independent of block structure) until a corresponding `#undef`
> directive is encountered or (if none is encountered) until the end of the preprocessing
> translation unit. Macro deﬁnitions have no signiﬁcance after translation phase 4.

So it doesn't take in count the function scope.